# Nodejs Set a global function and call a nested function

Tags: node.js, global-variables, global, global-functions

My Main function

```
import AppLauncher from './Applauncher'

function Mainfunc() {
 global.app=  AppLauncher()
 global.app.start('index')
}
```

AppLauncher.js

```
    function AppLauncher() {
      function start(opts){
              console.log('functions start called with' + opts)
        }
     }

   export default AppLauncher
```

I want to assign the AppLauncher function as global, and call the start function nested inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors are the way to go. You can do something like this:

```js
// AppLauncher.js
function AppLauncher() {
  // run some code...
  // notice `this`
  this.start = function(opts) {
    console.log('start function called with', opts);
  }
}
export default AppLauncher;
```

In your main function, call it with the `new` keyword:

```js
import AppLauncher from './AppLauncher';
function Mainfunc() {
  global.app = new AppLauncher();
  global.app.start('index');
}
```

Constructors can also be written as classes (you can use it the same way as in my last example):

```js
class AppLauncher {
  constructor() {
    // Anything in here gets executed when once you create an object from this class with the `new` keyword
  }
  // Instead of `this` we add a method to the class:
  start(opts) {
    console.log('start function called with', opts);
  }
}

export default AppLauncher;
```

More about constructors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

**If you don't want to use a constructor**, you can also return an object:

```js
// AppLauncher.js
function AppLauncher() {
  // Some code here...
  return {
    start(opts) {
      console.log("function start called with", opts);
    }
  };
}
export default AppLauncher;
```

And you can use this just like you thought:

```js
import AppLauncher from `./AppLauncher`;
function Mainfunc() {
  global.app = AppLauncher();
  global.app.start('index');
}
```

As a side note, it's conventional to call constructors with `PascalCase`, while regular functions are called with `camelCase`.